# Sharepoint error when deploying feature from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I get an error when I try to deploy the feature which just creates a new site collection in sharepoint even when build is successful.

Error message:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Feature definition with Id eeebb27c-ec18-4f87-8be6-e29c61fb53d5 failed validation, file 'SPFeature_Feature\Feature.xml':
>   Feature 'eeebb27c-ec18-4f87-8be6-e29c61fb53d5' is WebApplication-scoped, and cannot be added to the Site.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Edited. Would suggest you to read the FAQ about how to ask good questions. People will most probably request more info and/or code to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a fix to you. Click on **Features** folder of the solution in Visual Studio. Check the scope of the **FeatureX.feature** file and change it to **Site** level.

Hope this helps :)